# Add and remove a directory/file to the PATH

Tags: environment-variables

I want to learn how to add and remove a directory/file from the PATH but there are hundred answers and a lot of them are contradictory (or so I believe).

I have found answers that suggest editing `.profile` and others that say that this file is no longer supported for this job (or that is what I understand).

I have found answers that suggest editing `/etc/environment`.

Some other answers suggest editing '~/.bashrc' file.

Also I have found some answers suggesting writing something like `export PATH=...`

Currently I don't know which of these suggestions are correct, which of them are advisable to be used without causing any side effects in my system and I haven't got any idea hot to remove a directory/file from the PATH.

So how can I add and remove a directory/file from the PATH correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**/etc/profile** : A global configuration script that applies to all users.

**~/.bash_profile** :
A user's personal startup file. Can be used to extend or override settings in the global configuration script.

**~/.bash_login** : If ~/.bash_profile is not found, bash attempts to read this script.

**~/.profile** --> If neither ~/.bash_profile nor ~/.bash_login is found, bash attempts to read this file. This is the default in Debian-based distributions, such as Ubuntu.

**/etc/bash.bashrc** : A global configuration script that applies to all users.

**~/.bashrc** : A user's personal startup file. Can be used to extend or override settings in the global configuration script.

**export** – Export environment to subsequently executed programs

The `/etc/environment` file sets the variable system wide for every user on boot.

From the definition above, the criteria of adding and removing a directory/file from the PATH correctly is related to your needs.

Comment: @Adam Welcome friend

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/environment` is where the default PATH is set. To *remove* a directory from *that*, I suppose the easiest way is to edit it directly. OTOH I think you should think twice before doing so.

Otherwise, as has been mentioned in other answers, there are several possible places where you could *add* a directory. Also, the tutorial [EnvironmentVariable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables) provides useful guidance.